# This is not a number Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Here im going to create a database in phpMyadmin.it shows this is not a number error.Here i have attached the image.When im going to save it shows

> This is not a number!

[image]

Comment: What's your question? It's expecting a number and you aren't providing one, it's like any other form validation.

Comment: why don't You put length for INT type? It's missing.

Comment: @ripa : I think it is not mandatory to specify LENGTH of INT column.

Comment: @AbdulManaf yes You were right. I don't know that. then I check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053596/do-i-have-to-specify-integer-length-when-creating-an-id-field-in-mysql-through-p. Thanks for Your comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to enter length for `IsActive` as it is of type `BIT`. In Mysql `BIT` field requires a length to be assigned.

For more details about Data types and their lengths , check out this page

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30885&seqNum=7

Comment: BIT type is not listed in your links

Comment: @Simon the link was mainly to give extra idea about various data types and not particular for `BIT`. As you can read my answer it doesn't specify you can find the `BIT` data type info can be found in the link